# Real analysis questions, limits and bounds

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

Prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = ∞$ and $y_n$ is bounded, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n + y_n) = ∞.   $

Prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=∞$ and $|y_n|≥M$ for some $M >0$ and $∀n≥n_0 >0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_ny_n) = ∞.$

For the first one I let a be the limit of $y_n$, which is any number. So infinity + a would be infinity but I am not sure how to go about proving this. 
Completely lost on the second.

Comment: You can't assume $y_n$ has a limit, it's not given, and indeed that's the whole issue in the problem. As for the second one, take an $n_1$ that makes $x_n \geq N$ for $n \geq n_1$, then consider $n \geq \max \{ n_0,n_1 \}$ and see what you can do.

Comment: Ok, so how do I go about proving the first?

Comment: Expand out the definition of $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$ and then play around with n's and M's.

Comment: Neither of your explanations are very clear to me. Not sure if you could explain with more detail.

Comment: I can, but I don't think you've really looked at this carefully enough yet, so I would like to see some more of your work before giving specifics.

Comment: Are you allowed to use this theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem

Comment: Yes we are allowed to use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Still can not figure these out, any help would be great!!

Comment: For the first one $x_n+y_n\geq x_n-|y_n|\geq x_n-M.$ For the second one let $n>n_1\implies x_n>0. $ Let $n_2=\max (n_1,n_0).$ Then $n>n_2\implies x_ny_n>x_nM.$

Answer (score 0):

For the second proof, I would start with the epsilon-definition of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=\infty$, which is that $\forall K, \exists n_1$ such that for every $n\geq n_1, |x_n|>K.$
We know that there exists some $n_0$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0, |y_n|\geq M$.
So pick arbitrary K and fix it. let $n_2=\max(n_0,n_1)$. Then 
$$x_n y_n \geq M*K $$
for all $n \geq n_2$
Since we can find such an $n_2$ for any K, it follows that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_ny_n) = \infty$.